# Execute a shell command from a .NET application

Tags: .net, winforms, console, execution, shell

I need to execute a shell command from my .NET application, not unlike [`os.execute`](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OsLibraryTutorial) (a little way down on that page) in [Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29). However with a cursory search I couldn't find anything. How do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "blah.lua arg1 arg2 arg3";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.Start();
```

Another way would be to use [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) and use ShellExecute directly:

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr ShellExecute(
    IntPtr hwnd,
    string lpOperation,
    string lpFile,
    string lpParameters,
    string lpDirectory,
    ShowCommands nShowCmd);
```

Comment: i.e. putting `blah.lua somearg anotherarg thirdarg` in a console command.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to consider an asynchronous approach if the script takes a while.

Here's some code which does that plus redirects standard output to capture for display on a form ([WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), whatever). Note that I'm assuming you don't need user-input, so it doesn't create the console window, which looks better:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
...
// Wire up event in the constructor or wherever is appropriate
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
...
// Then to execute your script
worker.RunWorkerAsync("somearg anotherarg thirdarg");

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "blah.lua";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = (string)e.Argument;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.Start();
    result.Append(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    process.WaitForExit();
    e.Result = result.AppendLine().ToString();
}

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result != null) console.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    else if (e.Error != null) console.Text = e.Error.ToString();
    else if (e.Cancelled) console.Text = "User cancelled process";
}
```

Comment: +1 for using background worker properly and not blocking the whole thread. Much better user experience!

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to handle this in C#. Using the System.Diagnostics namespace, there is a class to handle spawning processes.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "App.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "arg1 arg2 arg3";
process.Start();

Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

There are additional parameters to handle things such as not creating a console window, redirecting input or output, and most anything else you'd need.