# Embedded awk for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, awk, embed

Is there an AWK-implementation for .NET?

To be more concrete, here is an example of the kinds of problems I want to solve:

```
Article number        Price          Package day
10.1002-50            $50            Tuesday
10.1002-51            $40            Monday
10.1002-52            $50
10.1002-53            $50            Tuesday
#start prepackaged
20.2001-51            $1             Monday
20.2001-52            $30            Tuesday
10.1002-54            $10            Tuesday
10.1002-55
#end prepackaged
10.1001-50
10.1002-50            $50            Friday
10.1003-50
10.1004-50
```

I want to get the article numbers, but skip the prepackaged ones.

Here's how I'd imagine one could solve it with an AWK-implementation available in C#:

```
using Awk.Extensions;
string[][] output = System.IO.File.ReadLines("C:\Temp\input.txt")
    .Skip(1)
    .Awk("/start prepackaged/,/end prepackaged/ {next}; {print $1}")
    .Select(fields => fields[0])
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();

foreach(var item in output)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This would then ideally produce the output:

```
10.1002-50
10.1002-51
10.1002-52
10.1002-53
10.1001-50
10.1003-50
10.1004-50
```

Does something similar exist? Are there some other powerful, line-based scripting libraries for .NET I should consider?

Further investigation shows that there's [Jawk, a Java implementation of awk](http://jawk.sourceforge.net/), which can also compile AWK scripts to Java bytecode! There seems to be a [direct port of this to C#](http://awkdotnet.codeplex.com/), although it doesn't seem very mature.

Another project for Java, [awk4j](http://awk4j.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html):

```
private static void case03() throws ScriptException {
  ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("awk4j");
  CompiledScript obj = ((Compilable) engine).compile("BEGIN{ printf ARGV[1] }");  // コンパイル
  engine.put(ScriptEngine.ARGV, new String[] { "hello," });
  obj.eval();  // コンパイル済みのスクリプトを実行
  engine.put(ScriptEngine.ARGV, new String[] { "world!\n" });
  obj.eval();
}
```

Here's a similar question: *[Is there a .NET library which will give me the ability to run awk scripts in a .NET environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851048/is-there-a-net-library-which-will-give-me-the-ability-to-run-awk-scripts-in-a)*

Comment: It isn't obvious why you need full awk here - can't you just use regular expressions and extract values from groups? See `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`

Comment: Yes, of course I could just implement the whole thing in C#, e.g. in a generator with a for-loop and a boolean state variable `if (inPrepackaged) continue;`. That wasn't the point of my question though ;)

Comment: This kind of mix is pretty strange, IMO. You can do same thing with TakeWhile/SkipWhile and a pretty small regex (or just a Split). **You don't need AWK** (unless you want to keep same syntax) but you may need to **rewrite an AWK expression in a LINQ way** (no need for state variables and things like that, just joins).

Comment: I challenge you to implement the above logic in LINQ! I guarantee it won't be pretty. Well that or very inefficient ;)

Comment: For sure it won't be pretty (well at least not as much pretty as an awk expression). That said...about efficiency...I'd suggest to try and measure, you may be pretty surprised (after all you're encoding a logic that AWK has to parse from a string).

Comment: Doesn't .NET or C# or whatever that is have a `system()` function or similar that'd let you just call awk and then read the output?

Comment: do you part from a file? you can use .net to run gawk  shell command  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1817573/3617531

Comment: I see there is this: https://awkdotnet.codeplex.com/. It says: `Project Description: An Awk interpreter in C#. It's basically a port from JAwk.`

Answer (score 4):

There is [AWK for .NET](https://awkdotnet.codeplex.com). AWK is great, and I use it on Linux.